# Basis pursuit algorithms for exponentially large matrices?

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, combinatorial-optimization, compressed-sensing

Are there any efficient algorithms/heuristics for basis pursuit for exponentially large matrices?

That is

$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{x \in \Bbb R^n}{\text{minimize}} & \lVert x \rVert_0\\ \text{subject to} & Ax = y\end{array}$$

where $A$ is an exponentially large matrix, i.e., $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ where $n = \Theta(2^m)$.

Comment: Is $\lVert x\rVert_0$ the number of non-$0$ entries of $x$?  If so, then it's positive, so taking its argument seems pointless.  Also, what is $y$?

Comment: (Also also, you somehow switched your delimiters, typing `\rVert x\lVert` instead of `\lVert x\rVert`.  I have edited to correct.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a minimal number of measurements required for uniform sparse recovery, i.e.: 
$$
m \asymp s \log(n)
$$
where $m$ is the number of measurements (the number of rows of your matrix) and $n$ is the ambient dimension of the signal (the number of columns of the matrix).

Adding the condition $n \equiv 2^m$ simply gives the condition 
$$
m \geq Csm, 
$$
Or $s$ is simply a constant independent of the dimension of the matrix. I don't think that's a useful think to look at.